# Стиль не применяется

Tags: javascript, php, css

Что. за. дела? Есть код в хедере (header.php):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>          
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/style.css"> //тут хранится код css файла, что будет приведен ниже
    </head>
    <body>
```

страничка 1(createquote.php):

```
<?php
    include_once("header.php");
?>

    <!-- Триггер/Открыть модальное окно-->
<button id="myBtn">Открыть модальное окно</button>

<!-- модальное окно-->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <!-- модальное окно содержание -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <p>Некоторый текст в модальном окне..</p>
  </div>    
</div>
```

Есть стиль для него в файле css(о котором говорилось выше - style.css):

```
.modal {
    display: none; /* Скрыто по умолчанию */
    position: fixed; /* Оставаться на месте */
    z-index: 1; /* Сидеть на вершине */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Полная ширина */
    height: 100%; /* Полная высота */
    overflow: auto; /* Включите прокрутку, если это необходимо */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Цвет запасной вариант */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Черный с непрозрачностью */
  }
  
  /* Модальное содержание/коробка */
  .modal-content {
    background-color: #fefefe;
    margin: 15% auto; /* 15% сверху и по центру */
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    width: 80%; /* Может быть больше или меньше, в зависимости от размера экрана */
  }
  
  /* Кнопка закрытия */
  .close {
    color: #aaa;
    float: right;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: bold;
  }
  
  .close:hover,
  .close:focus {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
```

И файл footer.php:

```
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="footer">
            <p>quotes.com</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Вся проблема в том, что стиль почему-то не применяется. Но если я запихну код стиля на страницу createquote.php, то проблем не будет. Почему? Что не так? Файлик подключен.

Comment: 100% какая-то тупая проблема, но я не вижу ее.

Answer (score 1):

Закрывать теги нужно корректно. Сейчас не закрыт тег `html`. В итоге браузер сам решит где его закрыть и дополнит разметку. Скорее всего он закрывает всего сразу после `<body>`. Встати тег `body` тоже не закрыт.

А в целом: почему `<body>` находится в `header.php` ?

Comment: Алексей Шиманский, тег закрыт в другом файле. Я решила все разбить, чтобы было удобнее. Мне по крайней мере. тег body и html закрыты в файле footer.php. Сейчас дополню вопрос, чтобы было яснее. Сразу не добавила..

Comment: пути-то корректные? можно посмотреть в консоли разработчика это

Comment: Да, корректные. 10 раз проверяла уже. все точно норм. в том же файле но другие стили к тому же применяются. Только к модальному окну не ххотят. Вт в чем шутка

Answer (score 0):

Так, кажется я решила проблему. Понятия не имею что это за приколы были.. Спасибо  всем кто помогал. сейчас все работает. ахах. странно. кеш был почищен и до того как я задала вопрос и после. проблема не решалась. в общем. эту тайну мне не раскрыть. сейчас все работает и хорошо

Comment: ну значит всё же кэш. просто не до конца очищен.... вообще при разработке лучше ставить всегда "disable cache" чтобы не мучиться

Comment: Спасибо большое! Буду иметь в виду